# Laravel Passport Deployment

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I created a rest api using laravel framework with laravel passport, and uploaded it to hostinger sub domain - api.website.com.
It works fine but my api is not working on the live server of hostinger.
I tested it using postman but this is the results

[image]

Comment: You want to call your api from the browser ? if no, then use the desktop agent it should work, if yes, then you will need to setup cors headers : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#cors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.